# Problem finding my chat room in its true form?

Tags: bug

I made a chat room and started a chat in it. Now all I can find of it is https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/christianity+stack+exchange+users+helping+give+philosophy+stack+exchange+answers. I can't find its true form by a chat room search. What's the problem?

Comment: How long ago did you create it? Do you have a link to your chat account profile?

Comment: @curiousdannii Thanks, I found it from my Christianity Chat Stack Exchange profile. It looks like chat rooms themselves are not part of any one Stack Exchange website. Maybe that's why I couldn't find it through a Christianity Chat Stack Exchange search. Maybe you could give something like that as an answer and maybe I would accept the answer. And I made the chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140054/timothy-bahry and my question that it refers to yesterday.